# With react-redux how do you implement immediate UI prior to asych update call to backend, then rollback if the update is unsuccessful?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga

With react-redux how do you implement immediate UI prior to asych update call to backend, then rollback if the update is unsuccessful?  (currently using redux-thunk, but could look to another framework like redux-saga if this addresses)

So rather than:

```
REQUEST UPDATE (no UI change) ==async==> 
 => RECEIVED UPDATE CONFIRMATION (update State & hence UI with change) OR 
 => ERROR
```

support implementing like this:

```
REQUEST UPDATE (update State, so UI changes) ==async==> 
 => RECEIVED UPDATE CONFIRMATION (no need for anything) OR 
 => ERROR so 'rollback' state update
```

So question is whether react-redux or redux-thunk can help support the concept of keeping track of an item who state was changed, but may have to be rolled back?  Trying to give the immediate feedback of a successful drag/drop which triggered an updated to the backend.

Comment: That has a name: optimistic UI update. Maybe this package helps you https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-optimistic-thunk

Comment: You can add a success key in your reducer and then use it to react on api call success. I don’t know how to do it with thunks. Just with sagas

Comment: @Héctor - thanks for the pointer

Comment: @victor.ja - would need to store the previous value as another state item I guess to fall back to this if need be I guess